# Magento 2: How to change the content of print order

Tags: magento2, sales-order, forms, order-email, print

I need to change the content of printed form of the order. (**My Account-> My Orders -> View Order ->Print Order**). Which file is to be edited for the changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Front page, the print order action will not generate the PDF like Admin does. It will generate the HTML.

We should take a look the print layouts under `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout`.

For example:

- `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print.xml`
- `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_guest_print.xml`

Comment: means if we want to customize print order then we have to change blocks and phtml file from both layout files you have mentioned am i correct please guide me

Comment: @hiteshbalpande yes, correct. You should take two files which I mentioned.